# Convert method signature & modify body of method

Tags: c#, expression, roslyn

I'm trying to modify the expression of a function.
I want to replace a functions input argument with a function that returns the same value.
The idea is to convert: `function (Foo foo) { return foo.ToString(); }`
with `function(Func<Foo> fooProvider) { return fooProvider().ToString() }`

Actually I don't even want to call the function passed to us, but directly use the body of the function.
So the real example does not get an `Func<Foo>` as input, but an `Expression<Func<Foo>>`.

Example code can be found below.
I assume I get an exception now because I change the signature of the function.
Although that is exactly what I want to do.

Some code:
The program

```
class Program
{
   public static void Run()
   {
      Expression<Func<int, bool>> isOdd = number => (number % 2) == 1;
      Expression<Func<string, int>> parseTextToNumber = text => Convert.ToInt32(text);

      var vistor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(isOdd.Parameters[0], parseTextToNumber.Body);
      var result = vistor.Visit(isOdd);

      Expression<Func<string, bool>> textRepresentsOddNumber = result as dynamic;

      //Expected something like this:
      Expression<Func<string, bool>> expectedResult = text => (Convert.ToInt32(text) % 2) == 1;
   }
}
```

The visitor class

```
private class ReplaceExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldValue;
    private readonly Expression _newValue;

    public ReplaceExpressionVisitor(Expression oldValue, Expression newValue)
    {
        _oldValue = oldValue;
        _newValue = newValue;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldValue)
            return _newValue;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

And the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' 
>       must return a non - null value of the same type.
>       Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.'

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours I did found something that works.

PS: Not sure if it is the most generic or best solution there is to this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> isOdd = number => (number % 2) == 0;
        Expression<Func<string, int>> parseTextToNumber = text => Convert.ToInt32(text);

        var visitor = new ReplaceExpressionVisitor(isOdd.Parameters[0], parseTextToNumber.Body);
        var result = Expression.Lambda(visitor.Visit(isOdd.Body), parseTextToNumber.Parameters);

        Expression<Func<string, bool>> textRepresentsOddNumber = result as dynamic;

        //test:
        var code = textRepresentsOddNumber.Compile();
        Console.WriteLine(code.DynamicInvoke("0"));//writes false
        Console.WriteLine(code.DynamicInvoke("1"));//writes true
    }
}

private class ReplaceExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldValue;
    private readonly Expression _newValue;

    public ReplaceExpressionVisitor(Expression oldValue, Expression newValue)
    {
        _oldValue = oldValue;
        _newValue = newValue;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldValue)
            return _newValue;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```